# check another rule with fluentvalidation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I have the following code to validate an entity:

```
   public class AffiliateValidator : AbstractValidator<Affiliate>
   {
    public AffiliateValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.IBAN).SetValidator(new ValidIBAN()).Unless( x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.IBAN));
     }
    }
```

And ValidIBAN() Code:

```
public class ValidIBAN  : PropertyValidator
{
    public ValidIBAN()
        :base("IBAN \"{PropertyValue}\" not valid.")
    {

    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        var iban = context.PropertyValue as string;
        IBAN.IBANResult result = IBAN.CheckIban(iban, false);
        return result.Validation == (IBAN.ValidationResult.IsValid);
    }

}
```

}

So,CheckIBAN method of IBAN class does the dirty job.

Now, what I need to to is apply the following rule for another property:
If DirectDebit (bool) is true, then IBAN can't be empty and also it must be valid.

I can do this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.DirectDebit).Equal(false).When(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.IBAN)).WithMessage("TheMessage.");
```

But how can I Invoke another rule, IBAN's rule in this case, in order to check if is or not valid?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Sorry. I'm not sure what had posted as title. But will keep in mind next time.

Comment: "C# fluentvalidation check another rule"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the problems are simpler than they seem. This is the solution I adopt to aply the rule for DirectDebit field.

```
    RuleFor(x => x.DirectDebit).Must(HaveValidAccounts).When(x => x.DirectDebit)
            .WithMessage("TheMessage");
```

and change the rule for IBAN also:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.IBAN).Must(IsValidIBAN)
                            .Unless(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.IBAN))
                            .WithMessage("The IBAN \"{PropertyValue}\" is not valid.");
```

...and then:

```
   private bool HaveValidAccounts(ViewModel instance,   bool DirectDebit)
    {
        if (!DirectDebit)
        { return true; }

        bool CCCResult = IsValidCCC(instance.CCC);
        bool IBANResult = IsValidIBAN(instance.IBAN);

        return CCCResult || IBANResult;
    }

     private bool IsValidIBAN(string iban)
    {
        return CommonInfrastructure.Finantial.IBAN.CheckIban(iban, false).Validation == IBAN.ValidationResult.IsValid;
    }
```

the trick is use instance parameter of Must() to do whetever I want.